# Quadratic congruences non prime numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruences

Prof wrote this:

$ \mathsf x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 mod 65 $

His next step is

$ \mathsf x^2 - 64 \equiv 0 (65) $

**How did it got there**? I mean, i presume that $ \mathsf x = 8 $ because 64+1 = 65 and 65 divided is 1 with no remainder. But how and why did he wrote it like that?

From

$ \mathsf x^2 - 64 \equiv 0 (65) $

He goes to $ \mathsf x^2 - 8^2 \equiv 0 (65) $

Factorizes to $ \mathsf (x-8)(x+8)  \equiv 0 (65) $

And i get the factorization but not how he moved the 8 and 64, any tips?

EDIT: still didn't use Fermat Little Theorem or Euleros Theorem.

Comment: By inspection, $1 \equiv -64 \pmod {65}$, so working mod $65$, one can freely replace $+1$ by $-64$. The reason why that's beneficial for this problem is that $x^2-64$ can be factored.

Comment: Also, your line which starts with "Factorizes to" is wrong. There shouldn't be a "$-64$" on that line.

Comment: Edited! But in general, what's the procedure?

Comment: The general procedure is to factor $65$ into prime power factors, solve the congruence modulo each prime power, and aggregate the results via the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Yeah i realized it, but didn't know how to put or if i could put it there without changing anything!

Comment: The fact that one can see ("by inspection") that $1 = -64 \pmod {65}$ is just a trick that defers the case analysis, saving a little work.

Comment: How many solutions (mod $65$) did you get in the end?